# Azure FormRecognizer from Python SDK fails with message "Specified model not found or not ready"

Tags: azure-sdk-python, azure-form-recognizer, azure-ai

Trying to submit document for form recognizer created in form recognizer studio using python api. I have tested the form successfully in form recognizer studio.

```
 from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
 from azure.ai.formrecognizer import FormRecognizerClient
    
 endpoint = "https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/"
 credential = AzureKeyCredential("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
 form_recognizer_client = FormRecognizerClient(endpoint, credential)
    
 path = r"3FE5A953-22D4-4197-B262-E195C3A2CE9F.pdf"
 with open(path, 'rb') as f:
     blob = f.read()
 poller = form_recognizer_client.begin_recognize_custom_forms(model_id='mymodel', form=blob)
 result = poller.result()
```

get exception

```
 azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (1001) Specified model not found or not ready, Model Id: mymodel
 Code: 1001
 Message: Specified model not found or not ready, Model Id: mymodel
```

I have tried recreating the model with every version of the API available - (2021-9-30-preview, 2022-1-30-preview, 2020-6-30-preview) and still no luck. I am using version 3.1.2 on the sdk. I have tried on version 3.1.0 and 3.2.0b5 and still get the error.

Answer (score 2):

What API version was the model built with in Form Recognizer Studio? If it is one of the preview API versions, then you need to use the `DocumentAnalysisClient` which was added in the beta SDK versions, such as 3.2.0b5. You can find a link to the sample to get a custom document analysis [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/formrecognizer/azure-ai-formrecognizer/samples/v3.2-beta/sample_analyze_custom_documents.py). The async sample can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/formrecognizer/azure-ai-formrecognizer/samples/v3.2-beta/async_samples/sample_analyze_custom_documents_async.py).